# MySQL - Select the least day of the current week, not necessarily the first day of the week

Tags: php, mysql, database

Using PHP/MySQL

I'm trying to create a select statement that gets the data from the least day of the current week (I'm using it to show data on a certain player 'this week'). The week starts on Sunday.  Sundays's data may not always exist therefore if the Sunday data isn't found then it would use the next earliest day found, Monday, Tuesday, etc.

My date column is named 'theDate' and the datatype is 'DATE'

The query would need to be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE name = '$username'
AND [...theDate = earliest day of data found for the current week week]
LIMIT 1
```

It would return a single row of data.

This is a query I tried for getting the 'this week' data, It doesn't seem to work correctly on Sunday's it shows nothing:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE playerName = '$username'
AND YEARWEEK(theDate) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY theDate;
```

This is the query that I'm using to get 'this months' data and it works even if the first day of the months data is not found, it will use the earliest date of data found in the current month/year (this query works perfect for me):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE playerName =  '$username'
AND theDate >= CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
ORDER BY theDate
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying this, you probably need an inner query:

```
select * 
from table_name tn
where tn.the_date = 
(select min(the_date) 
from table_name 
where WEEKOFYEAR(the_date) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())
and YEAR(the_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()))
```

viz, give me the row(s) in the table with a date equal to the earliest date in the table in the current week and year.

Comment: This query is giving me the data for the date of "2012-07-09" today is "2012-07-15" and it's a Sunday so I should be getting today's data "2012-07-15"

Comment: Well try the week function rather than week of year. Allows you to specify the first day of the week. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, replace `YOUR_DATE` with the date from the column you want (theDate):

```
SELECT ADDDATE(YOUR_DATE, INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(YOUR_DATE) DAY) 
FirstDay from dual
```

Did you try:

```
SELECT ADDDATE(theDate , INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(theDate ) DAY) FirstDay
FROM table_name
WHERE playerName =  '$username'
ORDER BY theDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I get 2012-07-01, 2012-07-08, 2012-07-15 but multiple of each.  I did from table_name - dual doesn't work for me.

Comment: The `select ... from dual` is only as an example of usage (and since I don't have the structure of your tables). About multiple results, you'll have to either use `GROUP BY` or filter it or `LIMIT` the results. If you want, you can use http://sqlfiddle.com to build the tables and show us the query that you're trying to construct (post here a link)

Comment: I get the correct value 2012-07-15 but still haven't got what I'm trying to do to work correctly,  I believe I have to do something differently if CURDATE() is a Sunday - I'll have to test it over the nest day or so to see how the results play out.

Comment: @Jsn0605 or, you can change the [*timezone*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) so you're one day forward ;)

Comment: I believe the answer I gave previously and replacing WEEKOFYEAR() with the WEEK() function as subsequenctly suggested will give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = '$username' 
AND your_data IS NOT NULL
AND WEEK(the_date,0 = WEEK(NOW(),0))
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(the_date,'%w') ASC
```